# Problem based on Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics

A number of different objects have been distributed into $n$ boxes $B_1 , B_2,...,B_n.$ All the objects from these boxes are removed and redistributed into $n + 1$ new boxes $B_1', B_2', ... , B_{n+1}'$ with no new box empty (so the total number of objects must be at least $n + 1.$)

Prove that there are two objects each of which has the property that it is in a new box that contains strictly fewer objects than the old box that contained it.

This is pretty obvious when exactly n+1 elements are there because one of the original boxes will have exactly 2 objects and they will be separated in the redistribution.
Can someone give a hint on how to generalize this?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts; if nothing else, it should be easy to analyze this for small $n$.  Also:  Why use the same expression to denote both the old and the new boxes?  That seems confusing.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Strictly fewer?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes,strictly fewer

Comment: Is there a reason you think this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an object $O_i$ that was placed in box $B_j$ and $B_k '$,  give it weights of

- $x_i = $ 1 over the number of objects that are in $B_j$
- $y_i =$ 1 over the number of objects that are in $B_k'$

The goal is to show that there is some $p, q$ such that $y_p > x_p$ and $y_q > x_q$.

Note: Thus far, this is essentially just a restatement of the problem in mathematical terms, but I've given you additional terminology/framework that might allow for further manipulation to arrive at a contradiction/conclusion/corollary.

**Hints towards a slution:**

To prove that there is one such object is a "standard"/"well-known" problem.

> Observe that $ \sum x_i \leq n$ and $ \sum y_i = n+1$, hence there must be some $ y_p > x_p$ else $ \sum y_i \leq \sum x_i$.

To prove that there is at least two such objects:

> Show that $ \sum (y_i - x_i) \geq 1$.

> Show that $y_i - x_i < 1 $.

Hence, there must be at least two objects with  $y_p > x_p$ and $y_q > x_q$, else the sum cannot be $ \geq 1$.
It is clear that equality can hold, so this is the strongest possible result.

Comment: Except the problem wants not one such $i,$ but at least two.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Let me update the goal. Yes, this approach still works for 2 objects.  Do you want me to add the next hint?

Comment: I don't want the next hint, but I'm n9t the OP.